# Python - ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 4/

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator

So for this one course I have to make a calculator.
I have everything working but for the divide function, whenever I run it I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Calculator.py", line 43, in <module>
    val3 = Mult(val1, val2)
  File "C:\Python27\Calculator.py", line 17, in Mult
    val1 = float(val1)
  ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 4/
```

Here is my code, I realize that I probably use many improper ways of doing things such as getting the operand out of the string but I don't really know any other way.

```
def firstNu(fullLine, symbol):
    return fullLine[0:fullLine.find(symbol)].strip()
def secondNumber(fullLine, symbol):
    return fullLine[fullLine.find(symbol) + len(symbol) : len(fullLine)].strip()
def Add(val1, val2):
    val1 = float(val1)
    val2 = float(val2)
    val3 = val1 + val2
    return val3
def Sub(val1, val2):
    val1 = float(val1)
    val2 = float(val2)
    val3 = val1 - val2
    return val3
def Mult(val1, val2):
    val1 = float(val1)
    val2 = float(val2)
    val3 = val1 * val2
    return val3
def Div(val1, val2):
    val1 = val1
    val2 = val2
    val3 = val1 / val2
    return val3

while True:
    equat = raw_input()
    if equat.find("+") == 1:
        operand = ('+')
        val1 = firstNu(equat, operand)
        val2 = secondNumber(equat, operand)
        val3 = Add(val1, val2)
    elif equat.find("-") == 1:
        operand = ('-')
        val1 = firstNu(equat, operand)
        val2 = secondNumber(equat, operand)
        val3 = Sub(val1, val2)
    elif equat.find("*"):
        operand = ('*')
        val1 = firstNu(equat, operand)
        val2 = secondNumber(equat, operand)
        val3 = Mult(val1, val2)
    elif equat.find("/"):
        operand = ('/')
        val1 = firstNu(equat, operand)
        val2 = secondNumber(equat, operand)
        val3 = Div(val1, val2)
    print(val1, operand, val2, "=", val3)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Lots of issues: Since you're using `equat.find(...) == 1` you're only supporting 1-digit numbers. Lines like `val1 = val1` should be self-evidently unnecessary. Your `firstNu` and `secondNumber` functions should be combined into one better-written function that returns multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

`find()` returns `-1` if the given substring is not found.  Python considers `-1` to be a 'truthy' value (as opposed to values like `0`, `None`, `[]` which are 'falsey'), so `equat.find("\*")` is evaluating to `True` when the substring `'*'` is not found.  Your if statements should look more like:

```
if equat.find("+") != -1:
```

The error occurs because, when you input a division equation, `equat.find("\*")` evaluates to `-1`, which is `True`, `firstNu` gets called with the operator `'*'`, and `fullLine.find(symbol)` evaluates to `-1`.  Python handles negative string indices by counting backward from the end of the string (list indices are handled the same way), so `firstNu` returns `fullLine[0:-1]`, which would be `'4/'` if the line were something like `'4/5'`.  `float()` doesn't know how to turn `'4/'` into a number, so it throws the error you're seeing.

You should also replace `firstNu` and `secondNumber` with something like

```
def parseNumbers(fullLine, symbol):
    symbol_ind = fullLine.find(symbol)
    if symbol_ind == -1:
        ## do some error handling
    return fullLine[0:symbol_ind].strip(), fullLine[symbol_ind+1:].strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a lot of that boilerplate by splitting on the operation first to get 3 components, then dispatching to one of the methods in the `operator` module, eg:

```
from operator import sub, add, div, mul
import re

for line in iter(raw_input, ''): # stop after just enter pressed
    try:
        num1, op, num2 = re.split('([-+/*])', line)
        print {
            '-': sub,
            '+': add,
            '/': div,
            '*': mul
        }[op](float(num1), float(num2))
    except ValueError:
        print line, '-- not valid'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest replacing `firstNu` and `secondNumber` with something like this:

```
def get_operands(equation, operator):
    return [number.strip() for number in equation.split(operator)]
```

And then assigning like:

```
val1, val2 = get_operands('345 + 123', '+')
```

Advantages over your method:

- Supports numbers of more than one digit
- Supports spacing around numbers and operator